# why doesnt this jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my program i have a jquery line

```
$( '#monsters[0]').animate( { left: "+=25" },500);
```

i have a array called monsters, but i dont see why that would make a difference, this code does work when i change the id to a different images id, and i put `('img')` instead it even works on the image with the id `monsters[0]` i am also sure this is the images id. however i run the above code and nothing happens to the image, no error appears in the console either, can anyone explain this?

[link here](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html), if that helps at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain values of array with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457327/obtain-values-of-array-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'#monsters[0]'` can't be parsed by jQuery as meaning the element has an id `"monsters[0]"`. It's parsed as a query for an element having as id `monsters` and an attribute `0`.

You may do

```
$(document.getElementById('monsters[0]')).animate( { left: "+=25" },500);
```

If you use it more than once you can build yourself a small utility :

```
function $$(id) { return $(document.getElementById(id)) }
```

so that you only have to do

```
$$('monsters[0]').animate( { left: "+=25" },500);
```

But you should probably avoid those id, they would for example bring you the same problem in CSS. Here it looks like a class or a data attribute would make more sense.

---

**Comment :**

There's of course the other solution of dynamically escaping the `[` and `]` characters (and later on the other ones that could arise). Don't do it : this makes the code much more complex, hides the fact that it works only for certain forms of id, and is much heavier : you build a string that jQuery will parse to understand you need the id and then jQuery will call `document.getElementById`. Direcly use `document.getElementById` to be clearer, more reliable and more efficient.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I detailed my explanation. Is that clear now ?

Comment: @trying Because jQuery uses the angle brackes like they are defined in CSS. As conditions, e.g. `a[href ^= 'https://']` (all links whose href starts with `https://`). You really should not have an element with the ID `monsters[0]` in the first place. Use `monsters_0` for example.

Comment: @Tomalak — You seem to be confusing square `[]` and angle `<>` brackets. "Conditions" isn't a very good term to use here, everything in a selector is a condition, they are attribute selectors. Why shouldn't he have an id like that in the first place?

Comment: I'm not confusing square and angle brackets. I could have said "predicates" but that's just another word for "condition". Why you should not have an ID like this? Because it interferes with the systems you use. It makes it harder to write CSS and jQuery, for example. It clutters the code with unnecessary escaping and makes it harder to understand due to the use of programming symbols in inappropriate places. An ID is supposed to be a string, it should not look like a bit of code, for reasons of practicality and sensibility.

Comment: @Tomalak i purposely want it to be like code because i often use it as code and just 1-2 times not

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight As I was very surprised by your accept, I updated my answer with a comment. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @dystroy The third variant would be `$("*[id='monsters[0]']")`, which would work without escaping as well. In any case, the OP already confirmed my suspicion that the IDs contain angle brackets because he evals them at some point. This verifies my point - it's bad and wrong and the the OP should not be using stuff like this in the first place.

Comment: I'm with you on your comment (the star is useless in that selector). But building a selector and then ask jQuery to parse it is ugly in my opinion.

Comment: i will be honest you are right, however atm i am building games to help teach myself, there is no intent to keep them in the future. hence i used the first answer in my code, so i accepted it, i did 1+ you, and i appreciate it, but for this specific program i used the other answer so i then accepted it, hope that helps you understand.

Comment: @Tomalak it seems that your right, but is there another better way of doing it? its the only way i can see with dynamically created objects, which i need to later access through their image element.

Comment: @dystroy jQuery is all about building selectors and asking jQuery to parse them. It's all done by sizzle in the end anyway (yes, I know there is QSA, but not all jQuery does can by done with QSA). The issue here is in the approach, not in the tool.

Comment: @trying It's hard to answer without seeing what exact problem you are trying to tackle. If you can provide a stripped down sample of your current set-up on jsFiddle, I can try and suggest a better way.

Comment: @Tomalak i think what i was looking for is jquerys, `.data()` in order to store info on a element, (i started jquery on friday - 3 days ago and im self teaching ). i think it will work for what i want.

Comment: @Tomalak see this question please - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578160/how-to-connect-a-javascript-object-to-a-dynamically-created-html-element-inside

Answer (score 5):

The characters `[` and `]` have special meaning in a selector (they indicate [an attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)). If you want to use them as part of an ID selector (or any other kind of selector) you have to escape them with a `\`.

Note that since you are expressing your selector as a string literal, you have to escape the escape sequences too.

```
'#monsters\\[0\\]'
```

Comment: very useful but in truth i needed `document.getElementById('monsters[0]')` (dystroy's answer) because im doing this dynamically that was just an example but really thank you

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight — There is nothing stopping you dynamically adding ``\`` characters to a string, so you shouldn't need to avoid using selector syntax.

Comment: your actually right after trying `document.getElementById('monsters[0]')` i realized im going to have to dynamically add escapes

Comment: can you make my life easier and tell me how i would best add those escapes or give me a link to an explanation please?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight — There's an example in the original answer. Once they are part of a string string, you treat them like any other character.

Comment: i meant dynamically add them based on the position of `[` and `]`

Comment: `str.replace(/([\[\]])/g, '\\$1')`

Answer (score -4):

`$( '#monsters').animate( { left: "+=25" },500);`

will do.

`$( '#monsters')` gives away a jQuery wrapped object.